# How do i determine if using phone or ipad that deals with select differently

Tags: javascript, html, select, responsive-design

My web application has a multiple select field, but it consists of 100 values and so when testing on my PC scrolling has to be used to see the whole list and control-click used to select multiple values, this doesnt make it very easy to use.

[image]

So I changed my application to have a button that brings up a modal dialog and then has two lists so you can just see the entries better and you can move one at a time if wish, the interface is more forgiving.

[image]
[image]

However, on an iPad or phone with the inital method the select works in a different way. It just shows one entry in the select box and then selecting brings up a list each one with a checkbox, and actually this works fine. But the new method doesnt really work for iPad, Phone.

**So i just want to be able to accurately identify if the users browser will display multi-select select as box with multiple values (pc) or a list with checkboxes (ipad/phone). In javascript how do i accuratly determine this please.**

Or, should I change the interface so that in all cases the user selects a button, and then it brings up a modal dialog with list of fields with checkboxes that users can select/deselect ?

**Edit:Update**

In the end I decided to use a series of checkboxes instead and so it now works the same for all platforms

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commonly used method to detect if the device is *iPad/iPhone* or *PC* is to check the `navigator.userAgent`. You can use this in your script:

```js
function isMobileDevice() {
  return /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
}

window.onload = function() {
  if (isMobileDevice()) {
    // Display list with checkboxes for iPad/iPhone
  } else {
    // Display display multi-select select as box for PC
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks good to know, but i have now decided to use checkboxes instead for all platform (see updated question)